# Convert images to png using image magick and not changing its name

Tags: bash, imagemagick-convert

I am using the following code to convert every image files in a directory and its subdirectories from other format to png format.

```
find $1 -type f -name '*.jpeg' -o -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.gif' -o -name '*.GIF' -o -name '*.PNG' |  xargs -n 1 -I {}  convert {} -set filename:base '%i' '%[basename]' '%[filename:base].png'
```

The images gets converted to png but I am getting wierd results.
The image **abc.jpg** gets converted to **abc.jpg.png** while I want the converted image to have a name **abc.png**.

I don't understand what's going on here. Can somebody help? I don't want to use morgify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert with same basename but other suffix:

```
find ... | xargs -n 1 -I {} convert {} -set filename:base '%d/%t' '%[filename:base].png'
```

> `%d`:     directory component of path
>
> `%t`:     filename without directory or extension (suffix)

See: https://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php